What was the (classical Greek?) story about a guy who made art (a statue?) that he fell in love with and she became alive?
The title was something like Agamemnon.
What happened to the guy?
I bet the story had a tragic ending. He probably goes to hell for some reason. And if the reason was something virtuous like love, that would make it classically tragic.
But whatever happens, I bet he didn't just fall in love and live happily forever with a clay girl statue. I hear a lot of guys do that these days, though.
What was the ending, anyway?

There are two sources for this story. First, Clement’s Exhortation to the Greeks. In this passage Clement, a Christian theologian, is trying to persuade the Greeks to give up their veneration of statues of the gods.

So the well-known Pygmalion of Cyprus fell in love with an ivory statue; it was of Aphrodite and was naked. The man of Cyprus is captivated by its shapeliness and embraces the statue. This is related by Philostephanus.
Clement of Alexandria (195). Exhortation to the Greeks, chapter 4. Translated by G. W. Butterworth (1919). London: Heinemann.

The Pygmalion in this account may be the same as the king of Cyprus mentioned very briefly by pseudo-Apollodorus (Bibliotheca 3.14.3). Philostephanus was a historian who lived in Alexandria in the 3rd century BCE; none of his works survive.
The other source is Ovid’s Metamorphoses, in which Pygmalion is a sculptor and the goddess Venus transforms the statue into a living woman:

When Pygmalion saw these women [the Propoetides], living such wicked lives, he was revolted by the many faults which nature has implanted in the female sex, and long lived a bachelor existence, without any wife to share his home. But meanwhile, with marvellous artistry, he skilfully carved a snowy ivory statue. He made it lovelier than any woman born, and fell in love with his own creation. The statue had all the appearance of a real girl, so that it seemed to be alive, to want to move, did not modesty forbid. So cleverly did his art conceal its art. Pygmalion gazed in wonder, and in his heart there rose a passionate love for this image of a human form. […]
The festival of Venus, which is celebrated with the greatest pomp all through Cyprus, was now in progress, and heifers, their crooked horns gilded for the occasion, had fallen at the altar as the axe struck their snowy necks. Smoke was rising from the incense, when Pygmalion, having made his offering, stood by the altar and timidly prayed, saying: “If you gods can give all things, may I have as my wife, I pray—” he did not dare to say: “the ivory maiden,” but finished: “one like the ivory maid.” However, golden Venus, present at her festival in person, understood what his prayers meant, and as a sign that the gods were kindly disposed, the flames burned up three times, shooting a tongue of fire into the air. When Pygmalion returned home, he made straight for the statue of the girl he loved, leaned over the couch, and kissed her. […] Timidly raising her eyes, she saw her lover and the light of day together. The goddess Venus was present at the marriage she had arranged and, when the moon’s horns had nine times been rounded into a full circle, Pygmalion’s bride bore a child, Paphos, from whom the island takes its name.
Ovid (8 CE). Metamorphoses, book 10, lines 243–298. Translated by Mary M. Innes (1955). London: Penguin.

In modern versions of the story, the statue is often named “Galatea”, after a different character in Ovid (see Acis and Galatea). The earliest work to use this name seems to have been a short play by Jean-Jacques Rousseau, first performed in 1770:

Il lève le voile en tremblant, & se prosterne; on voit la statue de Galathée posée sur un piédestal fort petit, mais exhaussée par un gradin de marbre formé de marches demi-circulaires.
Trembling, he [Pygmalion] lifts the veil, and prostrates himself. We see the statue of Galatea posed on a very small pedestal, but elevated by a tier of marble made of semi-circular steps.
Jean-Jacques Rousseau (1771). Pygmalion, page 5, stage direction. Geneva.


That is the ancient Greek story of Pygmalion, a sculptor who fell in love with his statue of a woman.  The stature was brought to life by divine favor.
George Bernard Shaw's play Pygmalion changes the plot a lot and is the basis for the musical movie My Fair Lady.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pygmalion_(mythology)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pygmalion_(mythology)
